# Finding the equation of a Tangent line to a graph at a specific point

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Trying to determine the tangent line to the graph of F(x)=x^3 at (2,8). I know you use the equation (F(Dx+x)-f(x))/Dx for this type of problem, and that you just plug in the x-value at the point to solve once you have the simplified equation; I am having trouble simplifying to remove the Delta-x values, though.

Comment: can you use $$F'(x)=3x^2$$?

Comment: use $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)}{\Delta x}$, expand $(x+\Delta x)^3$, cancel, simplify, find limit, put $x=2$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the tangent line of a function at a point is its slope, or more specifically, its derivative. Using limits to find a derivative, we have $$\frac{f(x+\Delta) - f(x)}{\Delta}.$$

When $f(x) = x^3$, from the binomial expansion $f(x+\Delta) = (x+\Delta )^3 = x^3+x^2\Delta+x \Delta^2+ \Delta^3$. Now we can substitute those values in, and we have:

$$\frac{x^3+3x^2\Delta+3x \Delta^2+ \Delta^3 - x^3}{\Delta}$$
$$=\frac{3x^2\Delta+3x \Delta^2+ \Delta^3}{\Delta}$$
$$=3x^2+3x\Delta+\Delta^2.$$

Since as $\Delta$ tends to $0$, any term with $\Delta$ will also tend to $0$, the only term without a $\Delta$ is $3x^2$, which is the derivative of $x^3$.

Now find the point's $x$-coordinate and plug that into $3x^2$ to get the slope at that point.

Comment: @Zeb It's important to know that when you reach a step like $3x^2 + 3x \Delta + \Delta^2$, any term with $\Delta$s will tend to $0$, because by definition of a derivative, $\Delta$ tends to $0$.